# How to hide the word textbox border?

Tags: c#, ms-office, office-interop

Using C# I have succeeded in opening a word document and writing text to it. Now I want to insert a text box into the word document also by using c# code and I succeeded with the code I found elsewhere on internet. This was the code:-

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape textbox = oDoc.Shapes.AddTextbox(MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 0, 0, 70, 30); //MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationVertical
textbox.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Date";
```

It worked fine. But my problem, I would like to hide the default border of the text box with c# code. I tried searching for it but could not find one.

Could anyone help me? Thanks in Advance
Unnikrishnan, India

Comment: Did you try `textbox.ShapeStyle = `? I would test it, but i do not have Word on my computer.

Comment: I tried for hours. However, at long last, I succeeded with the following code. textbox.Line.Visible = 0; or textbox.Line.Visible = MsoTriState.msoFalse. Surprising I found that such a simple information is not available on internet.

Comment: glad you got it sorted..

Comment: Thank you Trae Moore for giving me an idea to work on.

Comment: Can you please add your findings as a separate answer so that this question can be marked as correct and rep awarded.

Comment: Yes I will do it. I have one more thing to add regarding its right alignment within the textbox. sorry I did not get enough time to do it immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape textbox = oDoc.Shapes.AddTextbox(MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 0, 0, 70, 30);`         
textbox.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = dateTimePicker1.Value.toShortDateString();`//this will insert a ms word textbox on ms word document.
textbox.Line.Visible = MsoTriState.msoFalse;` // this will hide the border or line of textbox.
textbox.TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphRight;` //this will align the text within the textbox to rthe right side of the textbox.
```

//In this oDoc is the document added.
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
    `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document oDoc = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();`

//I tried it with visual c# express 2010 and word 2007 and 2010 on different computers with operating system of Windows XP and Windows 7.